# How to mouseover a WebElement using Selenium RC2 in Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, mouseover

Using Selenium's Firefox WebDriver 2.20, I need to display a tooltip that appears when the mouse hovers over a link on my web page.

I've tried using Selenium's Action class to do this, but I get a ClassCastException: $Proxy7 incompatible with org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
builder.moveToElement(link).build().perform();
```

The ClassCastException happens in the moveToElement() method, when the WebElement that I passed to the function is cast to a Locatable object. The method is:

```
public Actions moveToElement(WebElement toElement) { 
   action.addAction(new MoveMouseAction(mouse, (Locatable) toElement)); 
   return this;
}
```

I've also tried the code below, which resulted in the same error:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseDown(((Locatable)link).getCoordinates());
```

I've heard that these methods worked in previous Firefox versions but not with recent Firefox versions (I'm using FF12). If that is true, are there any other ways of simulating a mouseover in Selenium? Any help getting this function to work would be greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION**
After digging around for a while and trying different code snippets, I found a solution to the problem. For anyone who has this problem in the future, I had to disable native events for the Firefox driver, like so:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile(); 
prof.setEnableNativeEvents(false); 
cap.setCapability("firefox_profile", prof);
```

Comment: You seem to mean the Selenium WebDriver, there is no such thing as 'Selenium RC2'?

Comment: In your first example, line 3, you call `actions`, but your `Actions` variable is named `builder`. Is that just a copy-paste error? Otherwise, the code should work. Could you please post your exact Selenium version and the interesting parts of the stack trace?

Comment: Try to toggle the native events value of the firefox profile when you create the firefox driver object.

Comment: I'm using Selenium WebDriver 2.20 (previously called RC2) with Firefox 12. The actions variable in my code above is just a copy-paste error. I'll try to get a more detailed stack trace.

Comment: I pinpointed the problem somewhat better. The ClassCastException happens in the moveToElement() method, when the WebElement that I passed to the function is cast to a Locatable object. The method is:

  `public Actions moveToElement(WebElement toElement) {

    action.addAction(new MoveMouseAction(mouse, (Locatable) toElement));
    return this;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do that:

```
string script = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                        "evt.initMouseEvent('mouseover',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                        "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script, element);
```