# Cannot cast WebElement to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate resize a column from a table, by using Actions class this is my code:

```
public boolean resizeColumn(String columnToResize, String toColumn) {
    try {
        WebElement column = findElement(columnResize, columnToResize);
        WebElement moveToPosition = findElement(columnByName, toColumn);
        waitUntilClickable(column);
        //click on resize
        getSupport().clickAndHold(column);
        ..
        ...
```

In PageSupport class:

```
public void clickAndHold(WebElement onElement) {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.clickAndHold(onElement);
}
```

In Actions class:

```
 public Actions clickAndHold(WebElement onElement) {
    action.addAction(new ClickAndHoldAction(mouse, (Locatable) onElement));
    return this;
  }
```

But I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: eu.ohim.tmdsview.selenium.util.WebElementProxy cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable

Apparently it does not like the cast to Locatable, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE- WebElementProxy class**

```
package eu.ohim.tmdsview.selenium.util;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import eu.ohim.tmdsview.test.TestEnv;

/**
 * <class>WebElementProxy</class>. Defines all the interaction manners that the framework 
 * may perform with the application. 
 * @implements WebElement, WrapsElement
 *
 */
public class WebElementProxy implements WebElement, WrapsElement {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private By locator;

private WebDriver searchContext;

private WebElement element;

/**
 * WebElementProxy. Overloaded constructor.
 * @param searchContext. Webdriver search content
 * @param locator. By element
 */
public WebElementProxy(WebDriver searchContext, By locator) {
    this.locator = locator;
    this.searchContext = searchContext;
}

/**
 * WebElementProxy. Overloaded constructor.
 * @param searchContext. Webdriver search content
 * @param element. Webelement object
 */
public WebElementProxy(WebDriver searchContext, WebElement element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.searchContext = searchContext;
}   

/**
 * <method>getElement</method> method: recovers to the framework the WebElement selected to use it 
 * @return the WebElement selected
 */
private WebElement getElement() {
    //If the element is not null, the framework returns it
    if(element != null) {
        return element;
    } else {
        //If the elements has not found, the framework prints the problematic locator 
        logger.trace("findElement() [{}]", locator);
        return searchContext.findElement(locator);
    }
}

/**
 * <method>click</method> method: search the element and does click on it
 */
public void click() {
    infoWithScrenshot("click() [{}]", locator);
    getElement().click();
}

/**
 * <method>submit</method> method: search the element and submits it
 */
public void submit() {
    infoWithScrenshot("submit() [{}]", locator);
    getElement().submit();
}

/**
 * <method>sendKeys</method> method: search the element and writes the text passed as a parameter
 * @param CharSequence... keysToSend. Text to writes on the application
 */
public void sendKeys(CharSequence... keysToSend) {
    infoWithScrenshot("sendKeys() [{}] to element [{}]", keysToSend, locator);
    getElement().sendKeys(keysToSend);
}

/**
 * <method>clear</method> method: search the element and clears it
 */
public void clear() {
    infoWithScrenshot("clear() [{}]", locator);
    getElement().clear();
}

/**
 * <method>getTagName</method> method: search the element and catch the name of it
 * @return the name of the tag as a string
 */
public String getTagName() {
    logger.info("getTagName() [{}]", locator);
    return getElement().getTagName();
}

/**
 * <method>getAttribute</method> method: search the element and catch the attribute of it
 * @return the text inside the attribute element
 */
public String getAttribute(String name) {
    logger.info("getAttribute() [{}] from [{}]", name, locator);
    return getElement().getAttribute(name);
}

/**
 * <method>isSelected</method> method: search the element and selects it
 * @return a boolean value to know if is selected or not an element
 */
public boolean isSelected() {
    logger.info("isSelected() [{}]", locator);
    return getElement().isSelected();
}

/**
 * <method>isEnabled</method> method: search the element and checks if is enabled it or not
 * @return a boolean value to know if is enabled or not an element
 */
public boolean isEnabled() {
    logger.info("isEnabled() [{}]", locator);
    return getElement().isEnabled();
}

/**
 * <method>isEnabled</method> method: search the element and recovers the inside it
 * @return a string value with the text inside the element
 */
public String getText() {
    logger.info("getText() [{}]", locator);
    return getElement().getText();
}

/**
 * <method>findElements</method> method: search elements in the web code and returns them
 * @param by. By
 * @return The list of elements that have found, to use it
 */
public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
    logger.trace("findElements() [{}] on element [{}]", by, locator);       
    return getElement().findElements(by);
}

/**
 * <method>findElement</method> method: search an element in the web code and returns it
 * @param by. By
 * @return The element found to use it
 */
public WebElement findElement(By by) {
    logger.trace("findElement() [{}] on element [{}]", by, locator);        
    return getElement().findElement(by);
}

/**
 * <method>isDisplayed</method> method: search an element in the web code and check if is displayed
 * currently on the "ghost" window browser
 * @return Boolean value to know if the element is displayed currently or not 
 */
public boolean isDisplayed() {
    logger.trace("isDisplayed() [{}]", locator);
    return getElement().isDisplayed();
}

/**
 * <method>getLocation</method> method: search an element in the web code and gets his location
 * @return the Point where the element is
 */
public Point getLocation() {
    logger.info("getLocation() [{}]", locator);     
    return getElement().getLocation();
}

/**
 * <method>getSize</method> method: search an element in the web code and gets his size
 * @return the element Size of the element
 */
public Dimension getSize() {
    logger.info("getSize() [{}]", locator);     
    return getElement().getSize();
}

/**
 * <method>getCssValue</method> method: search an element in the web code and gets his Css value
 * @return a string with the property name
 */
public String getCssValue(String propertyName) {
    logger.info("getCssValue() [{}] on element [{}]", propertyName, locator);           
    return getElement().getCssValue(propertyName);
}

/**
 * <method>getLocator</method> method: search an element in the web code and gets his localization
 * @return the element localization
 */
public By getLocator() {
    return locator;
}

/**
 * <method>toString</method> method: makes as a string properly formated the WebElementProxy 
 * @return String properly formated
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ConstantsFramework.WEB_ELEMENT_PROXY_LOCATOR + locator + ConstantsFramework.ELEMENT + element + ConstantsFramework.CLOSE_BRACKET;
}

/**
 * <method>getWrappedElement</method> method: to obtain the wrappered element 
 * @return the WebElement to wrapper
 */
@Override
public WebElement getWrappedElement() {
    return getElement();
}

/**
 * <method>infoWithScrenshot</method> method: adds information to the screenshot taken
 * @param msg. String with a comment
 * @param Object... args. The screenshot
 */
private void infoWithScrenshot(String msg, Object... args) {
    if(TestEnv.instance().isAutomaticScreenshot()) {
        String imgPath = ScreenshotUtil.takeScreenshot();
        //If the image path exists
        if(imgPath != null) {
            msg += " [<a class=\"screenshot\" href=\"" + imgPath + "\" target=\"_blank\">before</a>]";
        }
    }
    logger.info(msg, args);     
}   

}
```

**UPDATE**
This is what I am trying to resize, click on: style="cursor: col-resize;

```
<thead>
<th id="grid_ipvalue" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Indication of the product" role="columnheader" style="width: 568px;">
<th id="grid_ApplicantName" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Owner name" role="columnheader" style="width: 426px;" aria-selected="true">
<span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;"/>
<div id="jqgh_grid_ApplicantName" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
</th>
<th id="grid_did" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Design number" role="columnheader" style="width: 311px;">
```

Here you can see the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8yRE.png)

Comment: what are you returning from `findElement(columnResize, columnToResize);` and what is in your `WebElementProxy` class

Comment: `findElement(columnResize, columnToResize);`  returns a WebElement which is the column I want to resize, should I copy here the hole `WebElementProxy ` class?

Comment: why dont you go for `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.clickAndHold(onElement);` why you want `new ClickAndHoldAction(mouse, (Locatable) onElement)` this

Comment: also post the `WebElementProxy` class code and try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023728/how-to-mouseover-a-webelement-using-selenium-rc2-in-firefox)

Comment: I just updated the question with the WebProxy class. I do go for  `Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.clickAndHold(onElement);` but the method clickAndHold in the class Actions requires `ClickAndHoldAction(mouse, (Locatable) onElement)` This is just the sourde code from Actions I did not modify it, but is it the first time I'm using that class so I'm not very sure if I'm doing it well

Comment: Are you implementing your own `Actions` class or its selenium's library

Comment: it's selenium's library [check this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/ClickAndHoldAction.java?r=c7e10b5e70d7030c9ad80117e2841dbdca1585cf)

Comment: What's the element's tagName.Is it possible to give the link for the webpage you're testing

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot give you the link but I updated my question with a piece of the html of the table and a screen shot I hope that can be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the html code you've posted it looks like you are using `jqGrid`.
So i've try to do the same in the [jqGrid demo site](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). It worked fine for me withour any error.

So try the same with simple code instead of factory model and then check

ChromeDriver version 2.15

Selenium 2.46

Sample code

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Madhan\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.get("http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"1\"]/td[2]/span")));
    //Click on the Loadingdata menu
    WebElement load = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"1\"]/td[2]/span"));
    load.click();

    //Click on the JSON Data sub menu
    WebElement json = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"3\"]/td[2]/span"));
    json.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#list2_amount > span")));

    //Amount column dragger span
    WebElement amountcolumn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#list2_amount > span"));
    //total column dragger span
    WebElement totalcolumn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#list2_total > span"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    //click and hold the amount dragger to total dragger to reize the column
    action.clickAndHold(amountcolumn).moveToElement(totalcolumn).release().build().perform();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I'm still getting this error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: eu.ohim.tmdsview.selenium.util.WebElementProxy cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable** 

in this line: `action.clickAndHold(amountcolumn).moveToElement(totalcolumn).release().build().perform();`

Comment: what's the selenium-driver version and ff/chrome/ie version along with the driver version you are using

Comment: selenium version is 2.41.0 and the chrome driver version is 2.16

Comment: use selenium 2.46.0 and try it

Comment: I change it to 2.46.0 and still the same error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: eu.ohim.tmdsview.selenium.util.WebElementProxy cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable**

Comment: Instead of using proxy go with normal code as above